# DomCrawler filter html tags

Tags: php, html, symfony, web-scraping, domcrawler

so trying to get the text content of html tags using Symfony DomCrawler

```html
<html>

<strong> This is a strong text </strong>
<strong> This is a strong text </strong>
<h2> this is a header 2 text </h2>



</html>
```

So goal is to get for example the text inside the strong 2 tag

im doing this but it is not working im getting an error that the node list is empty:

```
$ExtractText = $crawler->filter('strong')->eq(2)->text();
```

Comment: "_but it is not working_" meaning what? Empty page? Wrong element fetched?

Comment: getting an error (node list is empty)

Comment: is the above the actual HTML you are working with or an extract for the purposes of the question?

Comment: its just an example for the purpose of this post , im working with a full html page on bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

So after spending some time testing the error was in my Node traversing step

```
->eq(2)
```

it should be :

```
->eq(1)
```

as the 0 is counted

Hope this would help others